# Node.js script would break when requesting HTTP responses from a site that does not exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, request, response

Using Node.js, when one requests a HTTP response, in optimal circumstances, the request comes back with a HTTP response.

However, sometimes the request breaks because the site, for example, has a 404 code, or the site does not exist at all. When requesting a batch of URLs, if there is a 404 code on, say, the 200th URL out of 1000 URLs requested, the entire script breaks. Here is my code:

```
var hostNames = ['www.gizmodo.com','www.sitethatdoesnotexist123.com','www.google.com'];

for (i; i < hostNames.length; i++){

    var options = {
            host: hostNames[i],
            path: '/'
    };

  (function (i){
    http.get(options, function(res) {

        var obj = {};
        obj.url = hostNames[i];
        obj.statusCode = res.statusCode;
        obj.headers = res.headers;

        db.scrape.save(obj);
    }).on('error',function(e){
    console.log("Error Site: " + hostNames[i]);
    });
  })(i);
};
```

Is there a way, that for example, if the site does not exist, I simply skip to the next URL, instead of having the script break?

EDIT: Fixed. Thanks user DavidKemp

Answer (score 1):

Use a try/catch block to catch any errors that might occur, and then continue on from there.

For example:

```
var hostNames = ['www.gizmodo.com','www.sitethatdoesnotexist123.com','www.google.com'];

//moved the function out so we do not have to keep redefining it:
var get_url = function (i){
    http.get(options, function(res) {

        var obj = {};
        obj.url = hostNames[i];
        obj.statusCode = res.statusCode;
        obj.headers = res.headers;

        console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4));
    })
  };

for (i; i < hostNames.length; i++){

    var options = {
            host: hostNames[i],
            path: '/'
    };
    try {
       get_url(i);
    }
    catch(err){
       //do something with err
    }
};
```

Comment: After `catch(err){`, I put in `console.log("Error, moving onto next");`, however, I still received the `events.js:71, throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event` error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind an `error` handler to your request. I also cleaned up the code a bit.

```
hostNames.forEach(function(hostname), {
  var req = http.get({host: hostName}, function(res) {  
    var obj = {
      url: hostName,
      statusCode: res.statusCode,
      headers: res.headers
    };
    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4));
  });

  req.on('error', function(err){
    console.log('Failed to fetch', hostName);
  });
});
```

Comment: You can put a little links to the docs too: http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback

Comment: Thanks loganfsmyth. Could you do this for the try-catch method?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage Nope, try/catch will not work because the error is thrown asynchronously.

Comment: From what you are saying, the example shown above this (code sample demonstrated by Neal) won't work? (It indeed does not work, but I thought it was an error on my part).

Comment: @DavidKemp Your linking me to the documentation actually got me to make it work. Thanks!

Comment: @theGreenCabbage Glad to be of help

Comment: If this has answered your question, please mark it as accepted so it doesn't sit unanswered.

Comment: I really want to accept David's answer, but I cannot, since it was a reply. @DavidKemp could you post this as an answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use uncaughtException event. this let script run even after exception. [link](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception)

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
  console.log('Caught exception: ' + err);
});
```

Comment: Excuse me. Could you tell me where I would place this in my code?

Comment: You should place it at start first js file

Comment: But be aware - this will catch any errors in the process - not just problems with connecting to the server (It's a bit like `On Error Resume Next` or the `@` operator in PHP) - and will make other errors hard to diagnose.

Answer (score 0):

```
var hostNames = ['www.gizmodo.com','www.sitethatdoesnotexist123.com','www.google.com'];

for (i; i < hostNames.length; i++){

    var options = {
            host: hostNames[i],
            path: '/'
    };

  (function (i){
    http.get(options, function(res) {

        var obj = {};
        obj.url = hostNames[i];
        obj.statusCode = res.statusCode;
        obj.headers = res.headers;

        db.scrape.save(obj);
    }).on('error',function(e){
    console.log("Error Site: " + hostNames[i]);
    });
  })(i);
};
```

Added a callback for when there's an error. Logs the site that returns an error on console. This error is usually triggered by a 404 or request time is too long.

Answer (score 0):

The full docs are at http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback at the time of writing. [loganfsmyth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15482596/26479) provides a useful example.